# IE11 Not Responding to Change Event Listener Correctly (Caching DOM Component Always)

Tags: javascript, closures, dom-events, internet-explorer-11

So I have a page that has in the HTML a single download button. On page load, I call the below function to attach change event listener to all download buttons:

```
// FileUpload JS
export function registerFileUploadEvents() {
  const fileUploadElements = document.querySelectorAll('.file-upload')
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(fileUploadElements, (fileUploadElement) => {
    const fileInput = fileUploadElement.querySelector('input[type="file"]')
    fileInput.addEventListener('change', e => {
      const selectedFile = e.target.files[0]
      if (selectedFile) {
        e.target.closest('.file-upload').querySelector('.file-upload__filename').innerHTML = selectedFile.name // show uploaded file's name inside fileupload component
      }
    })
  })
}

// Main JS
import 'registerFileUploadEvents' from './FileUpload.js'
registerFileUploadEvents()
```

After that the user can add a new fileupload button, so as to upload another file  (don't ask me why they don't let the user upload multiple files at one go, it's a business decision). And because I want to attach the same event listener to this new button, this is what I did:

```
// CloneButton JS File
import 'registerFileUploadEvents' from './FileUpload.js'
// ... after adding cloned fileupload button
registerFileUploadEvents()
```

So this works perfectly well on all other browsers, the uploaded file's name is shown in each new component, like:

### ---------File upload component 1--------
xxx.jpg

### ---------File upload component 2--------
xyz.png

The problem is with IE11, which does something like this:

### ---------File upload component 1--------
xyz.png

### ---------File upload component 2--------
(empty)

I.e. when I press the upload button in the second component and uploaded xyz.png, instead of putting the file name xyz.png into the second component, it replaces the first component's filename.

It seemed to me that this is a case of the *fileInput* variable being cached, so I used closure to try and retain the scope:

```
export function registerFileUploadEvents() {
  const fileUploadElements = document.querySelectorAll('.file-upload')
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(fileUploadElements, (fileUploadElement) => {
    const fileInput = fileUploadElement.querySelector('input[type="file"]')
    fileInput.addEventListener('change', seriouslyMan(fileInput))
  })
}

function seriouslyMan(fileInput) {
  console.log(fileInput.getAttribute('id')) // For normal browsers and IE, logs respective IDs of 1st and second component

  return function() {
    console.log('fileinput should be scoped correctly', fileInput) // For normal browsers, when clicked 2nd component, 2nd component's DOM element is logged but for IE, the first component's DOM element is still logged
  }
}
```

So this returned function *should* retain the right scoped fileInput, but I've no idea why it doesn't on IE.

I've also tried to loop the input[type="file"] directly to add the event listeners, but the same thing happened.

I then tried creating a new function to attach change event listener directly and only to the newly cloned upload button:

```
newFileUploadElement.querySelector('input[type="file"]').addEventListener('change', (e) => {
      const selectedFile = e.target.files[0]
      if (selectedFile) {
        e.target.closest('.file-upload').querySelector('.file-upload__filename').innerHTML = selectedFile.name
      }
    })
```

Once again, this works just fine on all browsers except IE, which again pushes the second file name into the first component.

Then I tried to *not* add an event listener to the second component, and again when clicking the 2nd component it triggers the change event. Populating the first component of course. IE only of course.

By now I'm completely confused and no longer know how to debug this. Did I miss something obvious? Any suggestions on how to debug this will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: As far as I know, IE does not support arrow functions, you can check it. There may be other problems. If you can provide a minimal sample code snippet that can reproduce the problem, it will help solve the problem.